# How to load two keras model with same architecture but different weights into one graph?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For example, I have trained two VGG16 model, the weights is different, directly load the two model causes the second model's predict differs from its original predicts, like this:

```
model1=get_model('model1.h5')
model2=get_model('model2.h5')
p1=model1.predict(x)
p2=model2.predict(x)
```

If I load the second model in another graph, the result is normal, like this:

```
model1=get_model('model1.h5')
p1=model1.predict(x)
graph1 = Graph()
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
with graph1.as_default():
    session1 = tf.Session(config=config)
    with session1.as_default():
    model2=get_model('model2.h5')
    p2=model2.predict(x)
```

but actually I want to mix two model's result, like this:

```
x=concatenate([model1.output,model2.output],axis=1)
model=Model(input=inp,outputs=x)
```

in order to do this, the two model should be in the same graph.

I also tried rename layer name, but it did not work

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.name = layer.name + str("_2")
```

so, whats the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you have saved your model with `model.save(...)`, right?
I can't see what is in `get_model`, but it's probably not quite right, because both models should work as they worked before.

```
from keras.models import load_model, Model   
from keras.layers import Concatenate

model1=load_model('model1.h5')
model2=load_model('model2.h5')

finalOut = Concatenate(axis=1)([model1.output,model2.output])

joinedModel = Model([model1.input,model2.input], finalOut)
```

Comment: My original codes use model.save_weights(),and I load weights by defining the model at first,then use model.load_weights().This time,I changed to model.save() and load_model(),I load two model at once and load each model seperately，the predict results stay the same.Maybe I should use model.save() and load_model().I'm wondering what's the difference.

Comment: Well... probably there is something strange in `get_model()`. There shouldn't be a difference. `model.save()` saves the entire model, including the optimizer and the optimizer states. Saves layer names, layer configurations, everything. While `model.save_weights()` saves only the trainable parameters (even if you set the to be untrainable, of course). You may be recreating the model in a different way.

Comment: If you consider your question answered, please mark this answer as correct. :)